# Duplicate Hyperlink Tabs

Tags: docusignapi

I am using SOAP API to add hyperlink tabs on a document. The second recipient/signer is getting a duplicate link placed on top of the existing link. See attached screenshot.
No issues for the first signer though.

I have also noticed that though the signer can see the active link, the signed & completed  document displays an inactive link when added as a Tab through the API.

Is there a possibility that I can embed a link within PDF and Docusign can activate this link while signing?

Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "...getting a duplicate link placed on top of the existing link" -- but if you're seeing tabs in unexpected places within the envlope, a good first step in troubleshooting might be to execute a "Request Envelope" operation for the envelope, and compare Tab information in the response with the Tab information you specified in your Create Envelope operation.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:RequestEnvelope>
         <ns:EnvelopeID>ENVELOPE_ID</ns:EnvelopeID>
         <ns:IncludeDocumentBytes>false</ns:IncludeDocumentBytes>
      </ns:RequestEnvelope>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Regarding your statement that "the signed & completed document displays an inactive link when added as a Tab through the API" -- this DocuSign Community forum post (http://community.docusign.com/t5/Templates-and-Powerforms/Hyperlink-in-contract/td-p/25837) describes the expected behavior of the hyperlink for completed envelopes:  "*When the envelope is completed, the hyperlink will no longer be active from the member console but will be active from the Completed PDF.  However, it will appear as static text.*".

AFAIK, it's not possible for you to embed a link within a PDF and force DocuSign to 'activate' the link during the signing session.

**-- UPDATE #1 --**

Thank you for posting the "Request Envelope" response.  Interestingly, that response shows that the Envelope only contains a single 'HREF' tag -- assigned to the first recipient, but shared amongst all recipients:

[image: RequestEnvelope response]

I've attempted to reproduce the issue that you describe, but without success.  i.e., I created/sent an envelope with two recipients, and included a single 'HREF' (text) tab assigned to the first recipient (but shared).  When the first signer signs, he sees the link just fine:

[image: First Signer - Signing Session]

And when the second signer signs, the link appears exactly the same for her as it did for the first signer:

[image: Second Signer - Signing Session]

In your scenario, does the text string "TERMS & CONDITIONS" appear as text in the PDF itself -- and then perhaps you're trying to (exactly) overlay that text with a DocuSign (HREF) text tab?  If so, then perhaps that's what's causing your issue -- i.e., the overlay position isn't quite precise enough -- so the signer is seeing the "TERMS & CONDITIONS" text in the document itself, overlayed by the (slightly offset) Hyperlink that you've added using a DocuSign tab.

Comment: If you see the attached screenshot, you would see that "Terms and Conditions" in black text appears to be blurred/distorted. This is the hyperlink tab added through the API. First signer can view this text properly. For the second signer, another tab is added on top of the first tab. That's why it appears that way. How to fix?

Comment: Without seeing the XML you used to create the envelope and/or the response from a "Request Envelope" request (showing the tabs that exist in the envelope), it's impossible to say for sure what might be causing that issue.

Comment: You may view the xml now at [requestEnvelope](http://docusign.tnbci.net/requestEnvelope.txt)

Comment: @NVN if you place a recipient tab in location (X, Y) then place another tab for a different recipient at the same location, then the tabs will overlap and you'll experience what you're seeing for the second recipient.  One the first recipient signs, their tab(s) become part of the document.  To resolve, you should leave enough space so that you can space them out so they don't overlap...

Comment: I am placing the tab using offset by the search string with in the document and NOT using location (X,Y) or per recipient tab.

Comment: Updated my answer to include "Update #1".

Comment: Thank you for your time.  I have a white colored anchorString text embedded in the pdf so that "Terms & Conditions" link  can be overlay on top of this string. Though, I use (0,0) pixel offset, I see slight misalignment in the tab placement. Just curious how did place the link? By location or matching anchor String offset? Thanks Much!

Comment: In my test, I placed the link using X/Y coordinates.